# A small hitch when sharing on twitter

Tags: bug, mathjax

If I like the share link to share a question or answer on twitter, the text automatically generated has repeated characters whenever there is latex involved. For instance, here is one such tweet automatically generated:

> Answer:How does ∑p(k)\sum p(k) grow asymptotically where p(k)p(k) is the smallest prime factor of kk? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1224635/34692?stw=2

I believe both of the latex markup and an "ascii-ization" of the compiled latex is produced right next to each other. Is there a reason for this? I find it annoying because I always have to edit it out. I wouldn't care if either the latex markup or an ascii version was generated by itself, but not both at the same time! Can something be done? I frequently tweet Math SE questions (and get clicks!).

---

Also, some websites show a count of how many times a question has been shared. I would find it interesting if that were possible to add to the site.

Comment: (Technical remark: it's not ASCII version, it's Unicode version. Its uses symbols that do not exist in ASCII) ... Can something be done? Maybe Ilmari Karonen will be interested in fixing this with SOUP.

Comment: This problem still exists now in 2020.